# What font type was used in book found on post in stackoverflow?

Tags: font-identification, serif

I need identify this font (or similar) (please only free-fonts, google fonts will be preciated). Similar fonts will be also upvoted because really helps me too.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: We have a dedicated [thread](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions) that may help you to identy this font and look a likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is [Computer Modern (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern), an original design of Donald E. Knuth for use with his TeX typesetting system. It's the default font in every TeX environment set-up, and it has an extensive set of matching Math symbols, so it's still being used *extensively* in scientific publications.

It is classified as a modern Didone:

> - Straight (hairline) serifs without brackets.
> - Vertical orientation of weight axes. (The vertical parts of letters are thick.)
> - Strong contrast between thick and thin lines. (Horizontal parts of letters are thin in comparison to the vertical parts.)
> - An unornamented, "modern" appearance.
>     (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didone_(typography))

The original fonts were scaled to the required size with a unique system that allowed independent horizontal and vertical calculation of the stems, and then saved as bitmaps for use on that scale only. As such, it's hard to mimic the original technology with the modern 'linear' scaling technology that Postscript and TrueType offers -- some font packs offer different font files to use in different sizes.

Sample image:

[image: CMU Serif Roman]

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I've seen this now, but I think is not the same font http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476351/how-to-use-the-computer-modern-font-in-webpages

Comment: I'm 100% convinced it is. Note that that post mentions a couple of different sources; my image is from the http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/download.html link. All modern font files are *reinterpretations* of the original data, because of incompatibilities of the font design itself as well as its bizarre character set and extensive family.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be Century Schoobook, although the numerals seem a tiny bit "bolder" than the roman. It's definitely in the Century family. https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/century-schoolbook/